# Production uninitialized constant custom class stored in lib (heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, heroku, namespaces

I have a custom class stored in /lib (/lib/buffer_app.rb):

```
require 'HTTParty'

class BufferApp
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://api.bufferapp.com/1'

  def initialize(token, id)
    @token = token
    @id = id
  end

  def create(text)
    message_hash = {"text" => text, "profile_ids[]" => @id, "access_token" => @token}

    response = BufferApp.post('/updates/create.json', :body => {"text" => text, "profile_ids[]" => @id, "access_token" => @token})
  end
end
```

I'm attempting to use this this class in an Active Admin resource and get the following error when in production (Heroku):

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Admin::EventsController::BufferApp):
```

It's worth noting I have this line in my application.rb and that this functionality works locally in development:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)
```

If I try `include BufferApp` or `require 'BufferApp'` that line itself causes an error. Am I having a namespace issue? Does this need to be a module? Or is it a simple configuration oversight?

Comment: Could you have overriden the `config.autoload_paths` in `production.rb`?

Comment: @jokklan unfortunately, no... I just did a project search and that is the only location I'm changing the autoload_paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error line says it all, you should reference class as `::BufferApp`

Comment: To elaborate: you will need `::` in front to specify that the `BufferApp` is defined in the root namespace (without namespace). Otherwise will it try  to find `BufferApp` in your current namespace (`Admin::EventsController`).

Comment: This makes total sense... thank you guys! However, I still get the following: NameError (uninitialized constant BufferApp), is this likely the result of the lib dir not being properly loaded?

Comment: I included the path in require and was able to get it working: require "#{Rails.root}/lib" + '/buffer_app.rb' although I don't believe this is ideal

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same problem with Rails 5 alpha. To solve it, I had to manually require the file:

```
require 'buffer_app'
```

and not: (`require 'BufferApp'`)

Even if Michal Szyndel's answer makes great sense to me, after manually requiring the file, prefixing `::` to the constant was non influential in my case.

Anyway I  am not satisfied with the manual requiring solution because I need to add code which is environment specific. Why don't I need to require the files manually in development?

Comment: Same with Rails 5... odd.

Comment: the same happened for me with rails 5

Comment: Same for me in Rails 5. And **Why don't I need to require the files manually in development?**

Answer (score 6):

Change this

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)
```

to this

```
config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)
```

`eager_load_paths` will get eagerly loaded in production and on-demand in development.  Doing it this way, you don't need to require every file explicitly.

See more info on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19852844/12887).

Comment: 2018-Nov-2, Thank you! This work perfectly, I put my class in /lib/ folder, it work in development mode, but not production mode. so I add new `config.eager_load_paths` into `config/application.rb` then it work!