# confusing about autoload_paths vs eager_load_paths in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I read a post about the rails load_paths, here is the [link](http://hakunin.com/rails3-load-paths).

But, I am still confused about the difference between the `autoload_paths` and `eager_load_paths`:

I have tested them in a newly created Rails 4 project.  It seems that they run the same way, that auto-reload in the development mode but in the production mode.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Author of the linked article here. Here's an attempt to clear up the confusion, going off of @fkreusch's answer.

In Ruby you have to require every `.rb` file in order to have its code run. However, notice how in Rails you never specifically require any of your models, controllers, or other files in the `app/` dir. Why is that? That's because in Rails `app/*` is in `autoload_paths`. This means that when you run your rails app in development (for example via `rails console`) — none of the models and controllers are actually required by ruby yet. Rails uses special magical feature of ruby to actually wait until the code mentions a constant, say `Book`, and only then it would run `require 'book'` which it finds in one of the `autoload_paths`. This gives you faster console and server startup in development, because nothing gets required when you start it, only when code actually needs it.

Now, this behavior is good for local development, but what about production? Imagine that in production your server does the same type of magical constant loading (autoloading). It's not the end of the world really, you start your server in production, and people start browsing your pages slightly slower, because some of the files will need to be autoloaded. Yes, it's slower for those few initial requests, while the server "warms up", but it's not that bad. Except, that's not the end of the story.

If you are running on ruby 1.9.x (if I recall correctly), then auto-requiring files like that is not thread safe. So if you are using a server like puma, you will run into problems. Even if you aren't using a multi-threaded server, you are still probably better off having your whole application get required "proactively", on startup. This means that in production, you want every model, every controller, etc all fully required as you start your app, and you don't mind the longer startup time. This is called eager loading. All ruby files get eagerly loaded, get it? But how can you do that, if your rails app doesn't have a single `require` statement? That's where `eager_load_paths` come in. Whatever you put in them, all the files in all the directories underneath those paths will be required at startup in production. Hope this clears it up.

It's important to note that `eager_load_paths` are not active in development environment, so whatever you put in them will not be eagerly required immediately in development, only in production.

It's also important to note that just putting something into `autoload_paths` will not make it eager-loaded in production. Unfortunately. You have to explicitly put it into `eager_load_paths` as well.

Another interesting quirk is that in every rails app, all directories under `app/` are automatically in both `autoload_paths` and `eager_load_paths`, meaning that adding a directory there requires no further actions.

Comment: Very detailed! ;) It's worth to mention that if you add a path to `eager_load_paths` then in developement env it acts like `autoload_path` (loaded on demand). So there is no point to add paths to `autoload_paths` at all. (Rails 4.1.0)

Comment: @pablo Thanks for the mention, I've tried Rails 4.0.0 and 4.1.6, both works.

Comment: Thanks for the great detailed explanation. And for this part, "autoload_paths behaves differently in production between Rails 3 and 4",  I've tried, but no work. And I haven't found any doc on it, could you tell me where to find or how to test correctly? Thanks. (I've added `config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/tools)` to *application.rb*, and touched *foo.rb* under *tools* dir, echo `puts 'loading...'; class Foo; end` in *foo.rb*, and `rails c`, `rails c p` to check)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but after some investigation it seems that `autoload_paths` are **not eager loaded** in production. (Rails 4.1.7)
But the opposite is true, paths in `eager_load_paths` are added to the load path and autoloaded in development.

Comment: @hakunin - @BigBourin's correct that `autoload_paths` does NOT eager load in production. See [here](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/)

Comment: There was definitely an issue filed, I believe it was this one: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6850 that made me believe in Rails 4 they fixed this. fxn comment says "Autoloading is not threadsafe, therefore any code that the user wanted to auto load should be eager loaded, because he has put no requires for it." and I kind of took it for their direction. Surprised that they didn't do that. /cc @BigBourin

Comment: @hakunin you may want to edit your answer then, as without reading these supplemental comments, one might be led to believe this is indeed true (re: auto-eager-loading everything in `/app` in production)

Comment: Is it true that everything under app/* is eagerly loaded? Because I have [an active question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695129/) where our production server isn't finding classes in app/lib, which seems to me should fall under this app/* pattern. Is there any way to verify what paths Rails is actually using once it's running? I already noticed that the console seems to find my class, even in production mode... :/

Comment: It's amazing how many times `eager_load_paths` gets mentioned in various articles without ever once mentioning *what file this is in*?

Comment: @Trejkaz you can verify which files are in eager_load_path with:
``Rails.application.config.eager_load_paths``

Comment: Is this statement still correct 7 years later?

"It's important to note that eager_load_paths are not active in development environment"

As far as I can tell, nowadays eager_load_paths will be considered for auto loading as well (so you just need to specify eager load). Probably already since 2014: https://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/#autoloading_is_using_eager_loading_paths_as_well

Answer (score 13):

Basically, `autoload_paths` are paths Rails will use to try loading your classes automatically. E.g. when you call `Book`, if that class isn't loaded yet, it will go through the `autoload_paths` and look for it in those paths.

In production, it might be better to load those upfront to avoid autoload concurrent issues. For that, it provides the `eager_load_paths`. Paths in that list will be required upfront when your application starts.