# Rails 5 ignoring /lib class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've used [this method](http://www.jetthoughts.com/blog/tech/2014/08/27/5-steps-to-add-remote-modals-to-your-rails-app.html) for modals in rails. It works really well, but I've just upgraded to Rails 5 beta3, and now it's not working in production.

I get this error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)

NameError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::ModalResponder):

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:26:in `respond_modal_with'
app/controllers/tools_controller.rb:28:in `new'
```

Is my inheritance thrown off with Rails 5?

My `class ModalResponder < ActionController::Responder` is in `/lib` and works in development...

Looking for info on changes with rails 5, but sources are limited to my knowledge.

Comment: This seems like a bug in Rails 5.0.0. It is also present after being out of beta. For me, it only happens in production, not in development.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add a 'require' (on application.rb) with your classes inside the lib folder.

Like:

> require './lib/someclass'

I recommend you put it inside a Rails plugin.

Comment: can you describe the best process for making it a plugin? I moved the lib file to my /app directory so it would be included, but that's probably not best?

Comment: Sure! You can read more about rails plugins [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html).  It's better to test all and you can add load file settings inside the plugin. Just create a plugin and move you lib folder inside them, I recommend to create a file 'Foo' to add the requires. In your application.rb project just add require 'foo'. Sorry my english hahah.

Comment: You also can require the lib folder using: `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`

Comment: @Arvro adding `lib` to the autoload_paths alone doesn't seem to do the trick. You have to explicitly require the files you want to autoload in production. At least that's what I had to do to get it to work. Anyone knows if this is intended behaviour and why?

Comment: @Daniel This answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19852844/3182764. Basically, autoload will require your class when it will be called.

Comment: @Arvro perfect. Thank you! TL;DR for everyone else: add the lib path to `config.autoload_paths` and `config.eager_load_paths` to get your code loaded and required in production!

Answer (score 42):

In `config/application.rb`, change this:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

to this:

```
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

`eager_load_paths` will get eagerly loaded in production and on-demand in development.  Doing it this way, you don't need to require every file explicitly.

See more info on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19852844/12887).

Answer (score -2):

<s>It says it cannot find the `ApplicationController::Responder` which was moved out of Rails 4.2 into a separate gem.</s>

Add `gem 'responders'` to your Gemfile

Classes in `lib` are not autoloaded, you have to require them

Comment: I can select this as an answer if you can provide reasoning for why lib is not autoloaded. This answer is not detailed enough to merit a check.