# Undefined method error for including a module in a controller action in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, autoload, eager-loading

At the end of the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773266/confusing-about-autoload-paths-vs-eager-load-paths-in-rails-4) question is this statement.

> ...in every rails app, all directories
>   under app/ are automatically in both autoload_paths and
>   eager_load_paths, meaning that adding a directory there requires no
>   further actions.

I added an `autoload` folder in my `app` folder. In it I have a file named assemble_best.rb with the following contents to test it out:

```
# app/autoload/assemble_best.rb
module AssembleBest
  def best_assembly(user_id,incl_confirms)
    p "****"
    p 'yo! it worked!'
  end
end
```

In my controller I have:

```
best_assembly(current_user.id, true)
```

The error I get is:

```
undefined method `best_assembly'
```

In a variety of syntax for each I've tried adding before_action and require statements. I've also attempted putting the folder in the lib folder and adding auto load referencing the file in my application.rb. Nothing I've tried works. Also tried creating an initializer. I know I could add it to my application controller, but it is already huge. This is the first step toward reducing the size of that controller.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why the down vote? If you down vote a question you really should cite your reason so questions can be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't *include* that module anywhere. Hence the error. Do this in your controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include AssembleBest
```

Comment: @Jay, what environment is this question relevant to? This required a server restart?

Comment: @vee, restart in development. Yes, it didn't work until after restart.