# Multithreading in Rails: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, concurrent-ruby

I have a Rails app in which I have a Rake task that uses multithreading functions supplied by the concurrent-ruby gem.

From time to time I encounter `Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant` errors.

After Googling for a bit I found this to be related to using threading in combination with loading Rails constants.

I stumbled upon the following GitHub issues: https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/issues/585 and https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26847

As explained here you need to wrap any code that is called from a new thread in a `Rails.application.reloader.wrap do` or `Rails.application.executor.wrap do` block, which is what I did. However, this leads to deadlock.

The recommendation is then to use `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.interlock.permit_concurrent_loads` to wrap another blocking call on the main thread. However, I am unsure which code I should wrap with this.

Here's what I tried, however this still leads to a deadlock:

```
@beanstalk = Beaneater.new("#{ENV.fetch("HOST", "host")}:#{ENV.fetch("BEANSTALK_PORT", "11300")}")
tube_name = ENV.fetch("BEANSTALK_QUEUE_NAME", "queue")

pool = Concurrent::FixedThreadPool.new(Concurrent.processor_count * 2)

# Process jobs from tube, the body of this block gets executed on each message received
@beanstalk.jobs.register(tube_name) do |job|
    ActiveSupport::Dependencies.interlock.permit_concurrent_loads do
      @logger.info "Received job: #{job.id}"
      Concurrent::Future.execute(executor: pool) do
        Rails.application.reloader.wrap do
          # Stuff that references Rails constants etc
          process_beanstalk_message(job.body)
        end
      end
    end
end

@beanstalk.jobs.process!(reserve_timeout: 10)
```

Can anyone shed a light as to how I should solve this? The odd thing is I encounter this in production while other information on this topic seems to imply it should normally only occur in development.

In production I use the following settings:

`config.eager_load = true`

`config.cache_classes = true`.

Autoload paths for all environments are Rails default plus two specific folders ("models/validators" & "jobs/concerns").

`eager_load_paths` is not modified or set in any of my configs so must be equal to the Rails default.

I am using Rails 5 so `enable_dependency_loading` should equal to `false` in production.

Comment: In which Rails environments have you tried this and experienced the error? What are the `eager_load_paths` and `autoload_paths` for those environments? (usually found in `config/application.rb` and `config/environments/*.rb`)

Comment: Ah - I was about to ask the same questions as @anothermh. In your application.rb I suspect you have one of these two set, which should not be the case in production. Disabling autoloading with `
config.enable_dependency_loading = false` should help.

Comment: @anothermh please see modified answer. The path's I autoload, should I not do that for production (e.g. put this setting in development.rb and not in application.rb)? Do note that the the constants included in the circular dependency error message are not defined in those `autoload_paths`.

Comment: Are you using spring? Try disabling spring with `DISABLE_SPRING=1` in your environment.

Answer (score 8):

You likely need to change your `eager_load_paths` to include the path to the classes or modules that are raising the errors. `eager_load_paths` is documented [in the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).

The problem you're running into is that [Rails is not loading these constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19852844/3784008) when the app starts; it automatically loads them when they are called by some other piece of code. In a multithreaded Rails app, two threads may have a race condition when they try to load these constants.

Telling Rails to eagerly load these constants means they will be loaded once when the Rails app is started. It's not enough to say `eager_load = true`; you have to specify the paths to the class or module definitions as well. In the Rails application configuration, this is an `Array` under `eager_load_paths`. For example, to eager load `ActiveJob` classes:

```
config.eager_load_paths += ["#{config.root}/app/jobs"]
```

Or to load a custom module from `lib/`:

```
config.eager_load_paths += ["#{config.root}/lib/custom_module"]
```

Changing your eager load settings will affect the behavior of Rails. For example, in the Rails `development` environment, you're probably used to running `rails server` once, and every time you reload one of the endpoints it will reflect any changes to code you've made. That will not work with `config.eager_load = true`, because the classes are loaded once, at startup. Therefore, you will typically only change your `eager_load` settings for `production`.

**Update**

You can check your existing `eager_load_paths` from the `rails console`. For example, these are the default values for a new Rails 5 app. As you can see, it does not load `app/**/*.rb`; it loads the specific paths that Rails is expected to know about.

```
Rails.application.config.eager_load_paths
=> ["/app/assets",
 "/app/channels",
 "/app/controllers",
 "/app/controllers/concerns",
 "/app/helpers",
 "/app/jobs",
 "/app/mailers",
 "/app/models",
 "/app/models/concerns"]
```

Comment: I just figured, since I only load custom subdirectories of /app, is eager loading even required? I think I just read they are loaded by default as descendants of /app

Comment: Updated answer to respond. Short answer: no, they are not loaded by default.

Comment: Sadly the issue has resurfaced. I don't think this really is the solution in this case.

Comment: You're welcome to post a link to the repository, if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately I can't share this project. I think I should use any of the methods mentioned in my opening post supplied by rails but I don't know in which capacity. Maybe I will try to open an issue on GitHub for the Rails project.

Comment: @edwardmp Can you post your full `application.rb` and the full `production.rb` environment file? You can redact any sensitive info.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue while trying out two gems that handles parallel processing;

1. [pmap gem](https://github.com/bruceadams/pmap)
2. [parallel gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel)

For pmap I kept getting an error related to Celluloid::TaskTerminated and for parallel I was getting a Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant for when I ran it with more than 1 thread. I knew this issue was related to how my classes and modules were eager loading and race to be placed on a thread. I try enabling both of the configs to true `config.cache_classes = true` and `config.eager_load = true` in the development env and that did the trick for me.

Comment: Thank you! By setting both configs to true, it works for me too!

Answer (score 4):

In my gems (i.e., in `plezi` and `iodine`) I solve this with `if` statements, mostly.

You'll find code such as:

```
require 'uri' unless defined?(::URI)
```

or

```
begin
  require 'rack/handler' unless defined?(Rack::Handler)
  Rack::Handler::WEBrick = ::Iodine::Rack # Rack::Handler.get(:iodine)
rescue Exception

end
```

I used these snippets because of `Circular dependency detected` warnings and errors.

I don't know if this helps, but I thought you might want to try it.

Comment: Thank you. This might work in non Rails contexts, but in Rails I do not really manually require anything but all Rails classes are autoloaded instead.

Comment: @edwardmp My apologies, I assumed you were requiring stuff in your `rake` task, so that when you called `bundle exec rake` it was conflicting with autoloading symbols.

Comment: no problem, appreciate your input. Your answer would be helpful for all people encountering the same issue in non-Rails contexts.

Comment: This actually works on the context you describe, in my case i am using threads on a delayed job rake worker and i was getting the same circular dependencies errors but doing this approach was crazy since the code had a bunch of dependencies like that. If i just put the constants names before the thread spawn does the trick for me. This answer inspired my solution so thanks!!!

Comment: @aledustet - Happy to help :-)