# how do i autoload all ruby files in rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a rails 5 app and some of my directories in `app/` dont autoload. how do i set the app to automatically load stuff in directories like:

`app/workflows`
`app/validators`
 whether it be specs or a real server?

i tried:

`config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/*')` 
or
`config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/validators')`

but it doesnt work. how can i just load every file in `app/` directory?

EDIT

one of the classes that i need to have manually loaded in specs:

```
module Validator
  class Token < Base
    validate :date_correctness

    def initialize(decoded_auth_token: decoded_auth_token)
      @expiration_date = decoded_auth_token[:expiration_date]
    end

    private

    attr_reader :expiration_date

    def date_correctness
      return true if Date.parse(expiration_date) >= Date.today
      errors.add(:token, 'is expired')
    end
  end
end
```

`app/validators/token.rb`

Comment: You shouldn't have to set anything up. Your classes should autoload when they are in subdirectories of `app`. Can you show your code for one of the classes that doesn't load?

Comment: This answer to a related question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45357284/3784008

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'workflows', '{*/}')]
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'validators', '{*/}')]
```